# After restart UFW has problems

Tags: ufw

After a restart of the Ubuntu 18.04 server, I always noticed that services aren't available. If I use: UFW DISABLE and then UFW ENABLE, everything works fine until the next restart.
In the log file after a restart, I found:

```
Jan 20 13:50:57 localhost ufw-init[245]: Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules'
Jan 20 13:50:57 localhost systemd[1]: ufw.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 20 13:50:57 localhost systemd[1]: ufw.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 20 13:50:57 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Uncomplicated firewall.
```

What can be wrong? Is there any way to test user.rules?